# How to make statements in loop using modulo operator function?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, modulo

I am trying to have a statement printed out multiple times, but having different numbers in it
For example
Class one has 21 students and 5 empty slots.
Class two has 23 students and 3 empty slots.
.
.

I've managed to get the code for the modulo operator which would be

```
 String2 = "There are %s students and %s empty slots" % (23,3) 
 print(String2)
```

However, I don't know how to use a for or while loop in order to get this done numerous times without writing them individually

Thank you for your time,

Comment: It's not clear what your question - what's the expected output, given the input?

Comment: My expected output would be
There are 23 students and 3 empty slots.
There are 21 students and 2 empty slots.
There are 20 students and 5 empty slots.
There are 24 students and 4 empty slots.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your example , define your classes list in the below mentioned format

classes = [(class1,empty slots1),(class2,empty slots2),....]

```
classes =[(23,3),(21,2),(20,5),(24,4)]

for clas in classes:
    String = "There are %s students and %s empty slots" % (clas) 
    print(String)
```

it will print as you expected

```
There are 23 students and 3 empty slots
There are 21 students and 2 empty slots
There are 20 students and 5 empty slots
There are 24 students and 4 empty slots
```

Comment: @ilhanilkay ,You are welcome!. If its helped you . Please do upvote and verified it as answer.